# Highcharts: there are two columns after exporting XLS(excel),I want to add another column showing percentage

Tags: highcharts

There is a percentage showed in pie-chart, highchairs. But when I export it into excel, there are numbers not percentage in it. How can I add a column showed percentage? I have tried to check API, but I did not find the answer. Here are a  demo and an exported excel picture.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'city'
  },
  tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      allowPointSelect: true,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
      name: 'BeiJing',
      y: 4,
    }, {
      name: 'ShangHai',
      y: 16,
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/highcharts/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdn.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="chart"></div>
```

[image: exported excel picture:]

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, because actually the values that you have in `Brands` column are percents. Please describe more precisely what you expecting.

Comment: @daniel_s  Thank you.I have updated the code and image.Now `Series1` column is value, not percents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add hidden series which points values would be set basing on `percentage` parameter of points from main series. The best place to do that would be the `chart.events.load` function. Here is the code:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    events: {
        load: function() {
        var data = [];
        this.series[0].data.forEach(p => {
            data.push({
            name: p.name,
            y: p.percentage,
            color: 'transparent',
            borderColor: 'transparent'
          })
        })

        var s1 = this.addSeries({
            name: 'Percents',
            data: data,
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ot8cLsmg/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.redraw

Comment: It works,thank you! I solved it several hours ago in another way like yours, the answer is below.

Comment: In this case, percents and series are generated automatically, so you don't need to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way: when clicking the download button, the percentage data will be added,then it will be removed after downloading.Here is some code:

```
let percentsData = [
  {
    name: 'BeiJing',
    y: 20 // percents
  },
  {
    name: 'ShangHai',
    y: 80
  }
] 
function downloadExcel() {
  chart.series[1].update({data: percentsData});
  chart.downloadXLS();
  chart.series[1].update({data: []}); 
}
```

**Live example:** https://codepen.io/cr7love/pen/rZGVKx?editors=1010

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update